# Multiple checkboxes checked with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple checkboxes that are added with AJAX. I am trying to trigger a `click` if the checkbox is not checked, but this is not working for all the checkboxes.

```js
if ($(".variable_manage_stock").prop('checked') == false) {
  $('.variable_manage_stock').trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[0]">
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[1]">
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[2]">
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[3]">
```

Comment: what is your expectation from clicking on a checkbox?

Comment: What does *trying to trigger a click if the checkbox are not checked* mean? What are you actually attempting to do here because this doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: none of your checkbox seems to be checked and you should call your handler in that case. No need to trigger the `click` event

Comment: Give a different ID to the checkbox and pass it via onChange event. Then you will get the click of each element separately.

Comment: @ThanveerShah An ID for each one seems redundant to me, based on the information provided. The OP can probably iterate based on the class-name and its index.

Comment: *"not working for all the checkboxes"* - **please elaborate** - it is working for *some*? it's working for *one*? first one? other? it's only working where they're not checked?

Comment: it work for only for the first checkbox " [0] " and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the list that you are getting by `$(".variable_manage_stock")` as the following code does:

```js
var stockList = $(".variable_manage_stock");
stockList.each(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[0]">
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[1]">
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[2]">
<input type="checkbox" class="variable_manage_stock" name="variable_manage_stock[3]">
```